# How to group multiple parameters in Swagger 2.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

Is it possible to group multiple parameters to reference them in multiple routes?

For example I have a combination of parameters which I need in every route. They are defined as global parameters. How can I group them?

I think about a definition like this:

```yaml
parameters:
  MetaDataParameters:
    # Meta Data Properties
    - name: id
      in: query
      description: Entry identification number
      required: false
      type: integer
    
    - name: time_start
      in: query
      description: Start time of flare
      required: false
      type: string
    
    - name: nar
      in: query
      description: Active region number
      required: false
      type: string
```

And then reference the whole group in my route:

```yaml
/test/:
  get:
    tags:
      - TEST
    operationId: routes.test
    parameters:
      - $ref: "#/parameters/MetaDataParameters"
    responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

Is this possible with Swagger 2.0?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it's not possible to group parameters and reference the whole group in a route but feel free to make the suggestion [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/issues) for future enhancement

Comment: Ok thank you, it was my intention to create an suggestion, but I wanted to be clear that it does not exist already.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not possible with Swagger 2.0, OpenAPI 3.0 or 3.1. I've opened a feature request for this and it is proposed for a future version:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/445

Answer (score 1):

You can point your `$ref` to middle `.yaml` file, like this:

```yaml
    //middle.yaml  <-----
    
    - $ref: 'Default.yaml#/components/parameters/meta_id'
    - $ref: 'Default.yaml#/components/parameters/meta_time_start'
    - $ref: 'Default.yaml#/components/parameters/meta_nar'
```

Your `Default.yaml` file should be like this:

```yaml
    //Default.yaml  <-----

    components:
      parameters:
        meta_id:
          name: id
          in: query
          description: Entry identification number
          schema:
            type: integer
            example: 1
        meta_time_start:
          name: time_start
          in: query
          schema:
            type: string
```

Finally, your main file should be looks like this:

```yaml
    /test/:
      get:
        tags:
          - TEST
        operationId: routes.test
        parameters:
          $ref: "../parameters/middle.yaml"  <---- external yaml file
        responses:
            200:
              description: OK
```

NOTE: Your `$ref` should be without `-`. like in my example