# Parameters reuse in OpenAPI 3

Tags: swagger, openapi

While defining an API in OpenAPI v3, if multiple API paths use the same list of query parameters, is there a way to define them once and reference them from each path?

Imagine a common scenario where I have 5 different APIs for searching, but they all share the same query parameters such as "limit, bookmark, page, sort" etc.

### Response to possible duplicate

I am not asking about referencing 1 specific parameter at a time, but rather re-use a SET of parameters in several API paths. Therefore I don't think it is a duplicate of [How to define global parameters in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590197/how-to-define-global-parameters-in-openapi))

Comment: Are you using Springdoc or some other framework?

Comment: `openapi-generator`, however I'm asking about the OpenAPI specs, not framework specific

Comment: Why was this closed? The link question is not the same at all

Comment: Can you expand on why you think this is not a duplicate? I don't have a lot of knowledge here, but the question feels rather too brief to start with, so I am not sure how many re-open bites it is likely to get. Is the proposed duplicate radically different, or could a solution to this be derived from that? cc @Helen.

Comment: (It is best to use language that indicates you don't _think_ it is a duplicate. You may have overlooked something. I have no view on the matter, other than recommending diplomacy around community curation actions).

Comment: @NathanH Thanks for clarifying, please see [How to group multiple parameters in Swagger 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32091430/113116). That question is about OAS2, but the answer applies to OAS3 too. (The answer being "this is not supported.")

Comment: Thanks @Helen this question is indeed a match

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the common parameters to be included with a single line in the YAML specification, that doesn't seem possible as far as the specification itself is concerned.
Frameworks such as Springdoc (for Java) provides an `OperationCustomizer` interface that can be implemented to achieve such functionalities.